# Loading html inside sweet alert?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, sweetalert2

Here is my code for callling Swal:

```
window.swal({
    title: "Checking...",
    text: "Please wait",
    imageUrl: "{{ asset('media/photos/loaderspin.gif') }}",
    showConfirmButton: false,
    allowOutsideClick: false
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/' + target,
    data: {
        data: true
    },
    success: function(response) {
        window.swal({
            type: 'info',
            width: 900,
            padding: '3em',
            html: response,
            showCloseButton: true,
            focusConfirm: false,
        });
    },
    error: function(response) {
    }
});
```

Basically I'm making an ajax request that does a `return view('index', compact('data'));` in the controller.

The html that I'm trying to load inside Swal has a `<script src="my-file.js"></script>` inside it, but it does not get loaded when `Swal` is fired, so no events get fired when I click inside.

I've tried looking in the docs but I can't find anything. How will I get swal to load that file?

Comment: `return->view()` - Doesn't seem like valid PHP, can you show us your controller?

Comment: @Script47 hi, sorry I made a typo, I've updated my question.

Comment: I got it working now, I just did a `$.getScript('my-file.js')` before firing `Swal`.

Comment: If you have the time you could write this into an answer so that the next person who runs into an issue like this has a great reference on how to solve it.

Comment: @Mike I will, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding this line inside the `success` block:

```
$.getScript('my-file.js')
```